# Following is my viewcontroller ,it has margin from top in phone with notch display. What need to be done?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, ios13

[Image Of the View Controller On Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6bZt.png) **I have tried setting modalPresentationStyle to fullscreen but did not work.**
**It is working beautifully in devices without notch display. In Storyboard changed the presentation of viewcontroller to fullscreen but still didn't work.**

```
#import "DocumentServicesViewController.h"
#import "SendItToUsViewController.h"

@interface DocumentServicesViewController ()
{
    NSMutableDictionary *getMyRecordDataDict;
    BOOL  IsGetMyRecordsServiceAvailable, IsScanAtHomeServiceAvailable;
}
@end

@implementation DocumentServicesViewController
@synthesize alertClassObject,FromPushNotification;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setImages];
    [self allocAllObjects];
    if (!FromPushNotification)
    {
        [self getDocumentMenuDetails];
    }
    else
    {
        ScanAtHomeViewController *scanObject = [[ScanAtHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScanAtHomeViewController" bundle:nil];
        scanObject.FromPushNotification = YES;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:scanObject animated:YES];

    }

    if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if(((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height)==2436) {
            [self setStatusBarView];
        }
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}[Sample image of viewcontroller][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you layout, also I don't know expected result, 
I may guess You want light-gray status bar, you probably have top constraint to superview with 20pt constant.
if I'm right remove this constraint and add another one to safearea top with 0pt constant.

Read more about safe area [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area)

Comment: Expected result: status bar should be in blue colour. My Vertical space constraint is (First item-->View.Top,Relation-->Equal,Seconditem-->Superview.top,constant-->0,priority-->1000,multiplier-->1)